# Proof of the fact that normal convergence of power series in all the sub-subsets of a subset does not imply normal convergence in all the subset

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider a complex power series $\sum_{n\geq0}a_nz^n$, which has a radius of convergence $\rho>0$.

I will denote the series using the following notation $$B_{\rho}(0)=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<\rho \}$$ and $$B_{r}(0)=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<r \,\,\mathrm{with} \,\, r \in (0, \rho) \}$$

A theorem states that the power series converges **normally** in $B_{r}(0)$.

---

I do not understand the following statement:

> The fact that the power series converges normally in $B_{r}(0)$, that is, in **any** circle of radius $r<\rho$, **does not imply** that it converges normally in $B_{\rho}(0)$.

I intuitively understand the reason of that, since the normal convergence is something that involves all the points of a subset $S$ together, then the normal convergence in all subsets contained in $S$ cannot imply the normal convergence in $S$.

Nevertheless I would like to know if there is a way to prove this statement mathematically and with more rigor.

Answer (score 3):

By definition, $\sum_n a_n z^n$ converges normally in $B_\rho(0)$ if
$\sum_n \sup_{z \in B_\rho(0)} |a_n z^n| = \sum_n |a_n| \rho^n$ converges.

Consider e.g. the case where all $a_n$ = 1.  The radius of convergence is $\rho = 1$.
It doesn't converge normally in $B_1(0)$ because $\sum_n 1^n = \infty$, but it does converge normally in any $B_r(0)$ where $0< r < 1$, because $\sum_n r^n < \infty$.

This shows that it is possible to have a series converge normally in $B_r(0)$ for all $0 < r < \rho$ but not converge normally in $B_\rho(0)$.